# getSystemService need NOTIFICATION_SERVICE as Class<TypeVariable(T)!>

Tags: java, android, kotlin, notifications, android-notifications

So I want to create a notification reminder for my app. But when I want to create a notification channel, I already look at internet and documentation for the code but the getSystemService method show me an error.

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Class<TypeVariable(T)!> was expected
```

My code

```
private fun createNotificationChannel()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            val name = "Notif Channel"
            val desc = "A Description of the Channel"
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val channel = NotificationChannel(channelID, name, importance)
            channel.description = desc
//line below error
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(requireContext(), NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
//----------------
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }
```

Anyone know how to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

The correct usage is:

```
val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
```

or

```
val notificationManager = getSystemService(requireContext(), NotificationManager::class.java)
```

Answer (score 1):

An other way of using it is :

```
val  notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
```